# unrecognized database format access 2007 split database

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an MS Access 2007 split database. The Back End database contains 1 table. It is on a shared drive and front end has a data entry form with Macros, also a linked table from back end. Everyone in the organization has same version of Access (2007), same operating system etc.

Problem is I am able to open and add records to the front end but when anyone else try to open the front end it comes up with "Unrecognized database format" and they couldn't open it.

So far tried changing New database sort order to general - Legacy/ Compact and repair database from database tools but still not working for other users. Almost spent half a day searching and trying various solutions without success. Any help into right direction will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The lock file got corrupted. Delete it and re-open the application.

Comment: can you plz provide more details - do I need to delete the linked table from front end and reconnect? didn't quite got this

Comment: Look for the lock file that was created in the shared drive where the backend lives and delete it.

Comment: Thank you Frank :)

Comment: got to conclusion that if DB is created in Access 2010 then it wont open in 2007 and/or will loose some features